Showing almost sure convergence of Bayes Factor to zero
Suppose that for each $t\in\{1,2,3,...\}$, $X_t\overset{\text{iid}}{\sim}\text{Normal}(\mu_0,\sigma_0^2)$ for some known $\mu_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma_0>0$. Let $\mu_1\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{\mu_0\}$. Let $f(\cdot;\mu,\sigma)$ denote the $\text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ pdf, given any $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma>0$.
Now for each $T\in\{1,2,...\}$, define $\lambda_T$ as follows:
$$
\lambda_T = \frac{\prod_{t=1}^T f(X_{t};\mu_1,\sigma_0^2) }{\prod_{t=1}^T f(X_{t};\mu_0,\sigma_0^2) } \,\underset{\underset{\text{plug in, simplify}}{\uparrow}}{=\cdot\cdot\cdot=}\, \prod_{t=1}^T e^{-\left[\frac{(X_t-\mu_1)^2-(X_t-\mu_0)^2}{2\sigma_0^2}\right]} .
$$
I would like to show that $\lambda_T\overset{\text{a.s.}}{\to}0$ as $T\to \infty$. I am really rusty on formally showing almost sure convergence, so I am having trouble with this. Guidance would very much be appreciated.
Additional Context: Note that $\lambda_T$ is the Bayes factor comparing an incorrect model (which assumes that $X_t\overset{\text{iid}}{\sim}\text{Normal}(\mu_1,\sigma_0^2)$, with incorrect mean $\mu_1\neq \mu_0$) to the correct model (stated at the start of my question) after observing a sample of size $T$. I am new to the literature on model selection, but (as far as I know) the Bayes Factor should converge to zero almost surely here. If I am mistaken (e.g. "actually it converges in probability, not necessarily almost surely") please let me know (and I would appreciate guidance on how to formally prove the correct version of this statement). Thank you very much in advance to any and all that devote time to my question.

Hint: write $\frac{1}{T} \log \lambda_T$ in terms of $\hat{\mu}T := \sum{t \le T} X_t/T$. What do you know about $\hat{\mu}_T$ as $T$ diverges?

Firstly,
$$-\log\lambda_T = \sum_{t=1}^T {\left[\frac{(X_t-\mu_1)^2-(X_t-\mu_0)^2}{2\sigma_0^2}\right]}$$
and the required result is equivalent to $-\log\lambda_T \to \infty$ almost surely. Now
$$\frac{(X_t-\mu_1)^2-(X_t-\mu_0)^2}{2\sigma_0^2} =(\mu_0-\mu_1)\cdot \frac{X_t-\mu_0}{\sigma_0^2} + \frac{(\mu_0-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_0^2}$$
and so
$$-\frac1T\log\lambda_T = (\mu_0-\mu_1)\cdot\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{X_t-\mu_0}{\sigma_0^2} + \frac{(\mu_0-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_0^2}.$$
As $T\to\infty$, the first term in the RHS tends to zero almost surely by the strong law of large numbers, and so
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\left( -\frac1T\log\lambda_T \right) = \frac{(\mu_0-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_0^2}$$
almost surely. The RHS is strictly positive, and the result is proven.

You are amazing. Thank you, this was so very helpful.
